# Cannot find a matching 0-argument function named {NAME}METHOD() in built-in template rule

Tags: java, xml, xslt, sax, saxon

I registered ExtensionFunctionDefinition without parameters, but can not call it.
What is wrong and how this can be fixed?
Looks like function is unregistered.
Here is the code:

Saxon

```
     ...<saxon.he.version>9.7.0-3</saxon.he.version>...
        <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
        <artifactId>Saxon-HE</artifactId>...
```

Exception

```
Error at char 29 in xsl:value-of/@select on line 23 column 71 
XTDE1425: Cannot find a matching 0-argument function named {http://date.com}getFormattedNow()
in built-in template rule
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet ...
            xmlns:dateService="http://date.com"
            exclude-result-prefixes="dateService" version="1.0">
...
            <xsl:value-of select="dateService:getFormattedNow()"/>
```

ExtensionFunctionDefinition

```
public class DateExtensionFunction extends ExtensionFunctionDefinition {
public StructuredQName getFunctionQName() {
    return new StructuredQName("", "http://date.com", "getFormattedNow");
}

public SequenceType[] getArgumentTypes() {
    return new SequenceType[]{SequenceType.OPTIONAL_STRING};
}

public SequenceType getResultType(SequenceType[] sequenceTypes) {
    return SequenceType.SINGLE_STRING;
}

public boolean trustResultType() {
    return true;
}

public int getMinimumNumberOfArguments() {
    return 0;
}

public int getMaximumNumberOfArguments() {
    return 1;
}

public ExtensionFunctionCall makeCallExpression() {
    return new ExtensionFunctionCall() {

        public Sequence call(XPathContext context, Sequence[] arguments) throws XPathException {
                return new StringValue("TEST");
        }
    };
}
}
```

Transformer

```
    Processor processor = new Processor(false);
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    TransformerFactoryImpl transformerFactory = new TransformerFactoryImpl();
    processor.registerExtensionFunction(new DateExtensionFunction());
    configuration.setProcessor(processor);
    transformerFactory.setConfiguration(configuration);
    //...newTransformer
```

Answer (score 1):

The relationship between your Processor, Configuration, and TransformerFactory are wrong.

It's best to think of the Configuration as holding all the significant data, and the Processor and TransformerFactory as API veneers on top of the Configuration.

When you create a Processor, it creates its own Configuration underneath. Ditto for the TransformerFactoryImpl. So you have three Configuration objects here, the two that Saxon created, and the one that you created. The extension function is registered with the Configuration that underpins the (s9api) processor, which has no relationship with the one that you are using with the JAXP TransformerFactory.

I would recommend that you either use JAXP or s9api, but avoid mixing them. If you want to use JAXP, do:

```
    TransformerFactoryImpl transformerFactory = new TransformerFactoryImpl();
    Configuration config = transformerFactory.getConfiguration();
    config.registerExtensionFunction(new DateExtensionFunction());
```

Note that from Saxon 9.7, the JAXP interface is implemented as a layer on top of the s9api interface.

Comment: Thank you very much! But it still does not see function: TransformerFactoryImpl transformerFactory = new TransformerFactoryImpl();        transformerFactory.getConfiguration().registerExtensionFunction(new DateExtensionFunctionDefinition());

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that works (tested under Saxon 9.7 HE). I don't know why yours doesn't: please put together a complete program that illustrates the problem.

```
import ....;
public class ExtensionTest extends TestCase {

public class DateExtensionFunction extends ExtensionFunctionDefinition {
    public StructuredQName getFunctionQName() {
        return new StructuredQName("", "http://date.com", "getFormattedNow");
    }

    public net.sf.saxon.value.SequenceType[] getArgumentTypes() {
        return new net.sf.saxon.value.SequenceType[]{net.sf.saxon.value.SequenceType.OPTIONAL_STRING};
    }

    public net.sf.saxon.value.SequenceType getResultType(net.sf.saxon.value.SequenceType[] sequenceTypes) {
        return net.sf.saxon.value.SequenceType.SINGLE_STRING;
    }

    public boolean trustResultType() {
        return true;
    }

    public int getMinimumNumberOfArguments() {
        return 0;
    }

    public int getMaximumNumberOfArguments() {
        return 1;
    }

    public ExtensionFunctionCall makeCallExpression() {
        return new ExtensionFunctionCall() {

            public Sequence call(XPathContext context, Sequence[] arguments) throws XPathException {
                return new StringValue("TEST");
            }
        };
    }
}

public void testIntrinsicExtension() {
    try {
        TransformerFactoryImpl factory = new TransformerFactoryImpl();
        factory.getConfiguration().registerExtensionFunction(new DateExtensionFunction());
        String xsl = "<e xsl:version='3.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' " +
                "result='{Q{http://date.com}getFormattedNow()}'/>";
        Templates t = factory.newTemplates(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xsl)));
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        t.newTransformer().transform(new StreamSource(new StringReader("<a/>")), new StreamResult(sw));
        System.err.println(sw.toString());
    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException tce) {
        tce.printStackTrace();
        fail();
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        fail();
    }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><e result="TEST"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution** (works only for Saxon 9.4):

```
@Override
public ExtensionFunctionCall makeCallExpression() {
    return new ExtensionFunctionCall() {
        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public SequenceIterator call(SequenceIterator[] arguments, XPathContext context) throws XPathException {
            return SingletonIterator.makeIterator(StringValue.makeStringValue("TEST"));
        }
    };
}
```